# Using jquery to find html tags I want

Tags: jquery

I'm using bootstrap and trying to use loading state to make the main button to show "loading..." hen the dropdown links are clicked.

HTML codes

```
<div class="btn-group">
  <a href="#" data-toggle="dropdown" class="btn dropdown-toggle" id="test">
    Set
    <span class="caret"></span>
  </a>
  <ul class="dropdown-menu">
    <!-- dropdown menu links -->
    <li><a class="paid-today">Paid today</a></li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Javascript

```
$(function() {
  $( ".paid-today" ).click(function() {
    var $this = $(this);
    $this.closest("a").button('loading');
  });
});
```

When I did this, the dropdown link changed to "loading..." instead, not the main button.

Comment: your selectors are wrong. are you trying to change the text "Set" to "loading"?

Comment: Which is main button?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this

```
    $(function() {
       $( ".paid-today" ).click(function() {
         var $this = $(this);
         $this.closest("ul").prev().button('loading');
      });
    });
```

Comment: Emerson F, forget it! =)

Answer (score 2):

Try to target the button with a selector in

```
$( ".paid-today" ).click(function() {
    // here
});
```

If '#test' is the one you meant, use

```
$('#test').button('loading');
```

Or if you want to change the one you clicked,

```
$(this).button('loading');
```

---

I don't know what plugin you are using, but if it's just some styled link, you can simply use `.text("loading");` instead of `.button(...`

Comment: Why are you specifying a tagname with an ID? Edit: better, don't want to encourage bad habits